# Cannot figure out how to lower my motherboard onto the case

Tags: computer-building

I'm completely new to building PCs, and I've gotten to the stage where I'm lowering the motherboard. In all of the videos I've watched, they lower it in so easily, but mine meets serious resistance with the I/O shield. Every time I'm lowering it and attempting to line it up with the screws, the I/O shield inevitably gets in the way and "pushes" me back to the right. I feel like I have to jam the motherboard to the left to stop being pushed around by the I/O shield.

I don't know how aggressive I can be, and I'm terrified if rubbing the motherboard against the screws as I line it up.

It's making me want to give up. Do you have any advice?

Picture of the I/O shield's prongs:

[image: I/O shield's prongs]

Comment: You should verify the case is designed for the motherboard standard you purchased.  If you purchased an ATX motherboard, make sure the case, is designed for ATX motherboards.  The specifications of both your case and motherboard are online.

Comment: I can't help you in that case.  Given the information contained in your question, it is not possible, to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I built my first computer I was terrified that I would break components like the motherboard or connections when attached or detaching wires. It turns out that they are much tougher than I thought. Note that they CAN be broken or damaged, but if you're being very, very careful, then it's just likely that you need to use a little more force. Check for any obvious blocking issues. If it's just the spring taps of the IO then you're probably ok. Use your judgement and go slow. If in doubt, reach out to a friend who can take a look in person as I don't think that we can provide any more help in this situation

Comment: I really appreciate the answer. It gave me the confidence to go through with it and it went in. 